# C - socket programmation: test listen backlog

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, listen, backlog

I'm trying to test the listen backlog limits. I am collecting informations about this for some days, I know the backlog number provide to listen() is just a hint. But now I'm trying to create a server and a client (using TCP) to test the limit of the backlog.

On my server I use connect(), bind() and listen() and then sleep() for a long time.
On my client I use a loop which create the fdsock and use connect().

The server isn't accepting anything so I think that the connections goes to the backlog queue but the programm never stop, even after having crated more than 1000 sockfd.

Is there a way to test the backlog queue maximum limit ?

Thanks by advance.

EDIT:

```
#include "sys.h"

char *answer(char *port, int (*fun)(int)){
    struct addrinfo * info, * p, indices;
    struct sockaddr fromaddr;
    int fd, t, toclient;
    unsigned int len = sizeof fromaddr;

    memset(&indices, 0, sizeof indices);
    indices.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
    indices.ai_family = AF_INET;
    indices.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    t = getaddrinfo(0, port, &indices, &info);
    if(t != 0)
    {
        return "answer: cannot get info on port";
    }

    for(p = info; p != 0; p = p->ai_next)
    {
        fd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, 0); // fabriquer la socket
        if(fd >= 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    if(p == 0)
    {
        return "answer: cannot open socket";
    }

    t = 1;
    t = setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &t, sizeof t);
    if(t < 0)
    {
        perror("setsockopt");
    }

    if(bind(fd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) < 0)
    {
        close(fd);
        return "answer: cannot bind socket";
    }
    freeaddrinfo(info);

    t = listen(fd, 1);
    if(t < 0)
    {
        close(fd);
        return "answer: cannot listen on socket";
    }

    for(;;)
    {
        toclient = accept(fd, &fromaddr, &len);

        sleep(600);

        if(toclient < 0)
        {
            return "answer: cannot accept\n";
        }

        t = fork();
        if(t < 0)        // error
        {
            perror("fork");
            continue;
        }
        else if(t != 0)    // parent
        {
            close(toclient);
        }
        else             // child
        {
            close(fd);
            fun(toclient);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}

int foo(int n){
    char c;
    int t;

    printf("I have a new client\n");
    while((t = read(n, &c, 1)) > 0)
    {
        if(write(n, &c, 1) != 1)
        {
            perror("write");
            break;
        }
    }

    if(t < 0)
    {
        perror("read");
    }

    printf("I don't have that client anymore\n");
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char *p;
    p = answer(argv[1], foo);

    perror(p); 
    return 1;
}
```

And here is the code for my client:

```
# include "sys.h"

int dial(char *machine, char *port){
    struct addrinfo *info, *p, indices;
    int toserver, t;

    memset(&indices, 0, sizeof indices);
    indices.ai_family = AF_INET;
    indices.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    t = getaddrinfo(machine, port, &indices, &info);
    if(t != 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    for(p = info; p != 0; p = p->ai_next)
    {
        toserver = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, 0);
        if(toserver >= 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    if(p == 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    t = connect(toserver, info->ai_addr, info->ai_addrlen);
    if(t < 0)
    {
        freeaddrinfo(info);
        close(toserver);
        return -1;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(info);
    return toserver;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char buffer[1];
    int t, fd = dial(argv[1], argv[2]);

    while((t = read(0, buffer, sizeof buffer)) > 0)
    {
        write(fd, buffer, t);
        t = read(fd, buffer, sizeof buffer);
        write(1, buffer, t);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I set the backlog length to 1 then I let the server sleep for a long time so I can try to launch some clients but even if I launch hundreds clients they're never rejects.

Comment: connect, bind and listen on the server?  I would expect bind and listen to error out in that sequence.  Are you checking return codes?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just post my code so it's clearer for everyone. Basically, the question is: how can I test the listen backlog maximum limit by filling the queue ?

Comment: That's how. Test it by filling the queue. When you start to get connection refusals or timeouts (depending in the server platform) the queue is full. Of course you have to attempt more than one connection, unlike your current client code, which doesn't comply with your description at all. Your question?

Comment: Yes you're right, I don't post the right client, the one I'm talking about is the same with the dial function call in a loop. I test both clients and I can launch a lot of them without getting any connection refusals or timeouts.

Comment: So you have a large backlog. The minimum on some systems was as high as 500 twenty years ago. It could be in the thousands now.

Comment: But the backlog argument of listen() can't be useless. Isn't there a way to set a maximum number of connection in the backlog queue without using a manual counter ?

Comment: Your example won't compile (at least on Ubuntu 14.04.3 / gcc 4.8.4), can you post a working version of your server-side code?